# How to update function signature after modification with rlang::fn_fmls?

Tags: r, rlang

`rlang::fn_fmls<-` allows us to modify function signatures:

```r
f <- function(a, b, c) print(paste(a, c))
f_args <- rlang::fn_fmls(f)
f_args["b"] <- NULL
rlang::fn_fmls(f) <- f_args
f(1, 2)
#> [1] "1 2"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Clearly we've removed `b` from the function's signature. However, if we print the function itself:

```
f
#> function(a, b, c) print(paste(a, c))
```

`b` still appears in its signature. Using `args(f)` (which only prints the signature) actually works and `b` is omitted.

What should I do to get the function (with body) to print correctly, with `b` omitted?

Comment: @akrun yes, I mention that in my question. Is there a way of modifying the simple `f` though?

Comment: Check `attr(f, 'srcref')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `print.function()` has `useSource = TRUE`, which forces the use of the original function signature and body.

A solution I found would be to modify the function's class and create a custom print function.

```r
f <- function(a, b, c) {
  b <- 1
  print(paste(a, c))
}
f_args <- rlang::fn_fmls(f)
f_args["b"] <- NULL
rlang::fn_fmls(f) <- f_args
class(f) <- c("myfunction", "function")

print.myfunction <- function(f) {
  class(f) <- NULL
  print(f, useSource = FALSE)
}

f
#> function (a, c) 
#> {
#>     b <- 1
#>     print(paste(a, c))
#> }
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Either create a custom `print` function, or modify the source attribute.